# Salesforce Mobile SDK: Make sure you're running a packager server or have included a .jsbundle file in your application bundle

Tags: xcode, react-native, release, ipa, salesforce-mobile-sdk

I am trying to build a release ipa file for iOS (no problem when I edit scheme to Debug). And I got this error like image below:
[image]

My project is monorepo project, using Salesforce Mobile SDK with TypeScript.
Solutions I've tried:

- Run the command `react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/app/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest='./ios'` and add main.jsbundle to **Copy Bundle Resources** section.
- In **Build React Native code and images** section, change `export NODE_BINARY=node` to `export NODE_BINARY=$(which node)`
- Clean and Rebuild.